# Android: How to get latest intent triggered by NFC by calling getIntent() in onResume, in a running activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc

I just started using NFC tags for an Android Application development. 
The application contains a single activity, which is **MainActivity**.

**MainActivity** reads from NFC tags. I want to let it read from the latest detected tag by 
using ***getIntent()*** in ***onResume*** to get the latest intent. I did override ***onNewIntent(Intent intent)*** and call ***setIntent(intent)*** in it, and set **"singleTop"** launchMode for **MainActivity**.

However, when a tag is detected, system will call ***onResume()*** , and ***onNewIntent()*** is never called. ***getIntent()*** in ***onResume*** will always return intent of **action MAIN**, which is the original intent used when **MainActivity** is first launched.

Is there a way to get the intent that contains action **NDEF_DISCOVERED** in ***onResume()***?
Why isn't ***onNewIntent*** called?

I have the following code: (scala, just read it as java)

onNewIntent of MainActivity

```
override def onNewIntent (intent: Intent):Unit = {
  super.onNewIntent(intent)
  setIntent(intent)
}
```

onResume ()

```
override def onResume () :Unit = {
  super.onResume()
  var action:String = getIntent().getAction() // always get action MAIN
      ... }
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.tagwriter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- NFC intent filters -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/com.distributed.dmv" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: The intent filter for `NDEF_DISCOVERED` misses the `category` tag. Does your tag happen to have an Android Application Record on it? (That would explain that your app still gets an intent.)

Comment: i was about to say the same as @NFCguy! AARs just deliver an action MAIN intent - treat them as a back-up to a proper intent filter. (i.e. have records in the NDEF message in the tag)